# Why are my threaded comments not quite working?

Tags: comments

I had to switch from DISQUS as it got blocked in China and thus doesn't work and slows page loading down. I had hundreds of comments some were threaded, I got them to display correctly, but if I add a new comment replying to an old comment it doesn't thread.

This is my functions.php code which is from somewhere:

```
/* Add Theme Support for Threaded Comments */
add_action('get_header', 'enable_threaded_comments');
function enable_threaded_comments() {
    if ( ! is_admin()) {
        if (is_singular() && comments_open() && (get_option('thread_comments') == 1))
            wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
    }
}
```

This is my comments.php code again straight from somewhere else:

```
    wp_list_comments( array(
        'short_ping'  => true,
        'avatar_size' => 50,
    ) );
```

I did some styling and I used this [old post](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2007/06/10/just-beat-street-fighter-ii/) which some guy left a rather disturbing comment on recently to test and replying to my reply from back when I still had DISQUS does not create a third level. Thanks for any ideas in the console it says something is missing but when I try to debug it, the behaviour doesn't always occur, hence asking here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this, though I must "style" things better with CSS. In short my theme was not completely updated to WordPress 2.7. I needed one line of code in header.php and a few changes to comments.php it is all detailed [on Ottodestruct](http://ottodestruct.com/blog/2008/wordpress-27-comments-enhancements/).